# What's the proper way to clear the cache of the surf browser?

Tags: cache, browser

I've been using [suckless surf](https://surf.suckless.org/) for a while and the cache folder has been growing.

I can't find instructions in the manual related to clearing the cache.

I'm wondering if simply deleting the .surf/cache folder is the way to go.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, simply deleting `.surf/cache` is the way.

You can run `surf -d`. It will disable the disk cache and your cache folder will not grow up.